# Testing ViewContainerRef in angular6

Tags: angular

Hi I adding component dynamically using `viewContainerRef`.

```
export class DynamicComponentHolderComponent implements OnInit {

  comp: CompItem;
  @ViewChild(CompDirective) compHost: CompDirective;

  customUiList: Array<CompItem> = [];

  componentRef: any;

  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialogRef<DynamicComponentHolderComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public receivedData: any,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _componentService: CompService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.receivedData));
    this.getCustomComponentList();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    const dynamicItem = this.comp;

    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(dynamicItem.component);

    const viewContainerRef = this.compHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();

    this.componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
    (<CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance).data = this.receivedData.data;


    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance.
    updateEmitter.subscribe((response) => {
    this.dialog.close({ confirm: true, orderid: response.orderId, orderNumber: response.orderNumber });
    });

    // Default Close Emitter
    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.instance.
      closeEmitter.subscribe((response) => {
        this.closeDialog('close');
      });

  }

  getCustomComponentList() {
    this._componentService.getComponents()
      .subscribe(
        (response) => {
          if (response.length > 0) {
            response.forEach((comp) => {
              this.customUiList.push(comp);
            });
            const classNameIndex = _.findIndex(this.customUiList, (o) => {
              return o.data.displayName == this.receivedData.data.customComponent;
            });
            console.log('FROM COMP', this.customUiList);
            if (classNameIndex > -1) {
              this.comp = this.customUiList[classNameIndex];
              this.loadComponent();
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }

  closeDialog(param: any) {
    <CompComponent>this.componentRef.destroy();
    this.dialog.close({ confirm: false });
  }


}
```

Now i want to test, `this.componentRef.destroy();`. How can I do that in my spec.ts file. I have not idea how to do that. Need some help.